# Изучение php и JS

Tags: jquery, .net, delphi, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Необходимо быстро изучить php и js, изучить качественно и основательно. Могли бы посоветовать какие - нибудь книги/ресурсы/одни словом что - нибудь. Я достаточно неплохо знаю C, Delphi. Около года пишу на C# достаточно удачо, да и мне в принципе очень нравиться как язык, так и платформа .NET. Знаю, что под веб можно использовать и ASP.NET, но нужно именно php (js, jQuery).

Comment: поставил защиту, пока идёт голосование о (возможном) закрытии.

Answer (score 1):

"PHP5 в подлиннике Котерова" — хорошая книга, а по JS —  [Addy Osmani JS Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Answer (score 1):

Как бы ни банально это прозвучало, но php.su и javascript.ru
Сам учился именно по ним, всем доволен.

Comment: а есть что нибудь оффлайн ?

Comment: Оффлайновым не пользовался, поэтому увы, посоветовать нечего.

Answer (score 0):

"JavaScript. Подробное руководство" Д.Флэнаган - крутейшая книга по моему мнению + javascript.ru. После прочтение предыдущих ресурсов можно освоить статьи отсюда http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/?s=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8+ECMA-262-3

Answer (score 0):

Сайт https://learn.javascript.ru прекраснейший сайт для изучения чистого javascripta. Материал грамотно структурирован. К тому же после каждого раздела есть задачки и решения к ним.